# How can I multiply a number in an array by its position in the array and then add up the sum of the array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I multiply a number in an array by its position in the array and then add up the sum of the array in ruby?
I don't understand how to access the index of the array within the map function

For example: how can i get [5, 7, 13, 2]
to go to [5*0, 7*1, 13*2, 2*3]
then get the sum of this array.

ie

```
def array_method (numbers)
   numbers.map{|i| i* ?????}
end
array_method([5, 7, 13, 2])
```

this isn't working either its returning an empty array and I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You don't use your parameter at all in your method.  Check what `map` returns in the docs too.

Comment: You have not used numbers in your method. And if at all you had used it with what you have written you would have got an array having all the integers incremented by 1.

Comment: ok i have referenced the numbers paramater in the method but i still don't know how to call the index within the array.map numbers.map{|i| i * ?(in know its the index but I cant figure out how to reference it.)}

Answer (score 4):

You can monkey patch the `Array` class if you want the method to be available to all arrays:

```
class Array
  def sum_with_index
    self.map.with_index { |element, index| element * index }.inject(:+)
  end
end
```

**Console output**

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > [5, 7, 13, 2].sum_with_index
 => 39
```

Comment: Nice solution. But duno why am not a big fan of monkeypatching :)

Comment: It really depends on the context. If you're creating a new method rather than overriding an existing one, plus you need it to be available to all instances of that class, it's actually quite clean.

Answer (score 4):

```
 [5,7,13,2].map.with_index(&:*).inject(:+)
 # => 39
```

Comment: +1. Nicely done. The old symbol-proc "hack" sure has streamlined Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

```
[5,7,13,2].each_with_index.map{|value,index|value*index}.reduce{|a,b|a+b}
```

Comment: but how do I define a method in which I can use it on any array

Comment: @wfmonster `def doit(arr) arr.each_with_index.map{|value,index|value*index}.reduce{|a,b|a+b} end`

Answer (score 1):

```
def array_method (numbers)
   ans = 0
   numbers.each_with_index {| num, idx | ans += (idx) * num }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inject

```
def dot_product_with_index(array)
  (0..array.count-1).inject(0) {|r,i| r + array[i]*i}
end
```